# How to create empty folder/object in Minio using C#

Tags: c#, minio

I am using [MinIO Client](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/dotnet/minio-dotnet.html)

I am doing a pet-project for cloud storage. I want to create a new empty folder in an existing bucket. How do i do this?

I have already tried doing it this way:

```cs
    public async Task CreateFolderAsync(string path, string folderName)
    {
        var args = new PutObjectArgs()
            .WithBucket(_configuration["MinIO:Bucket"])
            .WithObject(path + folderName + "/")
            .WithStreamData(new MemoryStream(new byte[] { }))
            .WithObjectSize(0);

        await _minioClient.PutObjectAsync(args).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

but this code returns an error - System.InvalidOperationException: ObjectSize must be set

I haven't found any implementation of this one in c#, but I noticed that similar code works in java:

```java
minioClient.putObject(
            PutObjectArgs.builder()
                    .bucket(bucket)
                    .stream(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{}), 0, -1)
                    .object("files/testFoler/")
                    .build());
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Folders aren't really a thing in object storage, since everything is based on keys.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I want to have nested directories, maybe I should just use a database with tables: "files" and "folders", and s3 just as file storage, but I'm not sure that this way I can create the concept of a root folder

Comment: You don't really need to create a folder. You can just put a file to a/b/c/d and another file to a/b/c/e, and it will be handled for you. Things like S3, GCS, etc. use the / to demark folders, but in reality there are no folders, and it's just how the UI presents them.